# Why are horizontal scroll bars shown on my website?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and a horizontal scroll bar shows. Of course, I can use `overflow-x` and that will fix all my problems, but I want to know the origin of the issue. Can somebody tell me what makes the scroll bar show up? Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("rain.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 800px;
}

#header {
    width: 83%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: cyan solid 3px;
    border-radius:20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

p {
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: yellow;  
    position: relative;
    right: -450px;
    top: -8px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 83%;
    height: 1000px;
    top: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 225px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}

.click {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    right: -200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you have your `<p>` elements *relatively positioned* and shifted right with `right: -450px`.

With `position: relative` the original space for the element is reserved. So while you're shifting the element rightward 450px, its original space in the layout is kept intact, and the document is lengthened horizontally. That's the reason for the scrollbar.

[image]

Remove or adjust the `right: -450px` rule to see the difference.

Also, simply for contrast, switch `relative` with `absolute` positioning, which removes the element from the document flow, and the original space is eliminated.

[Read more about CSS positioning at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 3):

I'd point to this.

```
p{
    ...
    position: relative;
    right: -450px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use these lines

```css
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).