# CSS relative positioning and flow

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following layout. I've set my CSS so that the `p` element overlaps the first `div`.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.div-01 {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}
.div-02 {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}
p {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 100px;
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="div-01"></div>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <div class="div-02"></div>
</div>
```

But I also want it so that there is no gap before the green `div`, notice here that the green `div` is acting like the position of the `p` hasn't been modified.

[image]

I understand that this is normal behaviour, but is there any way to get the green `div` to appear straight after the `p`?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'd like it so that *all* elements after the `p` act as though the `p` hasn't been moved with relative positioning exactly, but as though it's natural position is as though it was overlapping the blue `div`

So basically no gaps in between any elements that follow the `p`

I also can't use `absolute` positioning, because it's unclear how tall any of the elements will be in the real thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same amount of negative `margin-top` on green div as `bottom` position of blue div.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.div-01 {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}
.div-02 {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
p {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 100px;
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="div-01"></div>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <div class="div-02"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I thought I'd have the same problem with `margin-top` for some reason, but looks like that works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that this is normal behaviour, but is there any way to get the green div to appear straight after the `p`?

Yes, apply the relative positioning to both elements. In other words, give the green div the same `bottom: 100px` as the `p` above it.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div-01 {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.div-02 {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}

p {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 100px;
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="div-01"></div>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <div class="div-02"></div>
</div>
```

Of course, this means that elements below `div-02` will see this element in its original position.

For an understanding of how relative positioning works see my answer here: [Why are horizontal scroll bars shown on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35678266/3597276)

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments)

> ... I meant so that there are no gaps in any of the elements that follow...

In that case, remove all relative positioning and just use `margin-top: -100px` on the `p`.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div-01 {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.div-02 {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}

p {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: -100px 100px 0;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="div-01"></div>
  <p>Hello world</p>
  <div class="div-02"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah thanks but I dont think I was clear enough, I meant so that there are no gaps in any of the elements that follow (I've amended my original question)