# Why is our website allowing horizontal scrolling on mobile screens?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I've been at this for 3 hours now and can not for the life of me find out why or what is causing our page (at a mobile width) to be scrolled horizontally.

I recorded a video of my issue. I have been in dev tools for hours and am about to pull my hair out.

## VIDEO

Any thoughts? Its a word press site.

You may also test for yourself on the actual **[Website](https://vapesocietysupplies.com/)**.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Most likely caused by that thing at the bottom where it tells you "someone from xyz made a purchase"

Comment: nope thats been there for ages. This has only been a problem for 2 days

Comment: I just messed up somewhere and not sure whats pushing it over or hidden in that space. Driving me nuts ahaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spent a few minutes deleting elements in Chrome Dev Tools until I found the one that was causing a horizontal scroll on mobile: it's the image with credit card logos in the footer (`.cc-reference`). It's being positioned with `margin-left: 50%;` and `left: -140px`, which is a little hacky and created extra space due to relative positioning pushing over the 50% of space.

Update the styles like so to fix it.

Before:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px)
    .cc-reference {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 50%;
        left: -140px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -8px;
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px)
    .cc-reference {
        float: none;
        display: block; /* making it block level allows you to... */
        margin: -8px auto 0; /* center automatically */
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay great leme look. Thanks!

Comment: I just floated it to the left instead of none which solved the issue. Thank you soo much for finding the target problem!

Comment: @PortalP The element should not be floating at all, considering it's on its own line. Your change fixed it due to a technicality, but wouldn't you rather be centering the element automatically instead of specifying hardcoded negative pixels?

Comment: Applied. Appreciate the extra tip.

Answer (score 1):

Focus your attention on this image buried deep in your `#bottom-footer`.

In mobile view, when I deleted the image, the horizontal scroll disappeared.

[image]

You've got the image relatively positioned and with a `left: -140px`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px)
.cc-reference {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: -140px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Unlike absolutely positioned elements, relatively positioned elements keep their original space (i.e., they are not removed from the document flow). Hence, you're adding 140px width to the image element, causing a horizontal scroll.

I've seen this before and wrote a more detailed answer (with an illustration of the behavior) here:

- [Why are horizontal scroll bars shown on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35678266/3597276)

Comment: Cool looking now and will get back to ya. Thanks!

Comment: I just set it to float:left; donno why I was using none. Think that solved the issue. Awarded for detailed description and linking to similar issue.

Comment: Oops my bad, I am going to award Jon because I ended up using his solution exactly and its less code. Thanks!