# How to apply a description over an image using CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid of images that display descriptions over a faded-out version of the image when the user hovers over said image. My current progress can be seen below and at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmose1106/5sLcgs0u/5/).

```css
div#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 25px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  
  div {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    // cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    
    img {
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    p {
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      top: -40px;
      left: 10px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    &:hover {
      
      img {
        opacity: 0.35;
      }
      
      p {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid Test</h2>
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kEmy7gp.jpg" alt="A Rock" />
    <p>A beautiful rock structure.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my example JSFiddle, what I am doing currently has these nasty black bars, as well as a resizing issue due to the relative placement popping up. I can get rid of the relative black bar using `margin-bottom`, but it still doesn't fix my issue with needless resizing.

Ideally, I would like to have an entire `div` over the image so I could position things within that div, but I have no idea how I could go about that without making a complete mess. I would like some assistance with how I could go about this logically with the following constraints:

- I'd prefer to not use JavaScript, but I am not 100% against it. But certainly no frameworks.
- I do **not** want to make the images `background-image`s of my `div`s.
- The images must be resizable. (though it may be worth noting that the initial size of the images is known)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons for the problem.

### Problem #1: `position: relative`

Your paragraph element is being relatively positioned over the image.

```
div#grid-container div p {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    top: -40px;
    left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The problem is that relative positioning *does not* remove an element from the normal flow. Therefore, even though you're using `top` and `left` to position the text, the original space for the element remains in place ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35678266/3597276)).

You need to remove the element from the normal flow so it doesn't occupy space in the container. Use `position: absolute` and make the parent the bounding box with `position: relative`.

```
div {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: relative;  /* new */

p {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /* adjusted */
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 40px;       /* adjusted */
    left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[revised demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/5sLcgs0u/9/)

---

### Problem #2: `vertical-align: baseline`

Your image elements are children of grid items. This means they don't participate in grid layout. They exist in block layout, where inline-level elements are automatically given baseline alignment with the `vertical-align` property ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height)).

That's why there's a small gap underneath the images ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)).

To fix the problem, override the default with `vertical-align: top`.

```
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;  /* new */
}
```

[revised demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/5sLcgs0u/8/)

Comment: I would better use `display: block` for images instead of changing `vertical-align` default.

Answer (score 1):

What you *could* do, is using the `:after` property on the `div` to position a half transparent dark background on top of the image and make benefit of the usage of `position: absolute;` on the paragraph element. See below and [this updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/42pnmxzm/) on JSFiddle. Read more about `:after` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

```
div {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    // cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    position: relative;

    img {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    &:hover:after {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }

    p {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      margin: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  remove the background-color in the div and put it in the p, and set the display to block in the p with an opacity of 0, in hover change the opacity to 0.65, and add a padding-left to the p and reduce the margin top:

```
    div#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 25px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 15px auto;

  div {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    // cursor: pointer;

    color: white;

    img {
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    p {
      opacity: 0;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      top: -20px;
      left: 0px;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
      background-color: black;
    }

    &:hover {

      img {
        opacity: 0.35;
      }

      p {
        opacity: 0.65;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could even play with the opacity of the image, I would put at least 0.75

Comment: You could even play with the opacity of the image, I would put at least 0.75